# Can I create a procedure in MySQL where I will just pass any table name from already created tables and get the records displayed using call

Tags: mysql

I tried this...

delimiter //

create procedure pselect(in tname varchar(50))
begin
select * from tname ;

end //
delimiter ;

call pselect ('trainee');

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.